# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'" while deployment in Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am trying to deploy a **WAR file** in Weblogic the first time, not sure what is wrong with weblogic server. I did some level of google search as well, somebody says try changing the browser, I have tried with Chrome, Forefox & IE but no luck.

I can see below error in  **Diagnostics > Log Files > DataSourceLog**. Please help me on this.

**WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0**

```
Error opening /jsp/diagnostics/ViewDataSourceLogTable.jsp. 
The source of this error is:
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:417)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jspService(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:111)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:526)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.scoping.internal.ScopedRequestDispatcher.include(ScopedRequestDispatcher.java:119)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.JspContent.beginRender(JspContent.java:552)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.beginRender(NetuiContent.java:365)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:485)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._wlsconsole.__nolayout._jspService(__nolayout.java:119)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._wlsconsole.__twocollayout._jspService(__twocollayout.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:211)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:196)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.printTableRows(CursoredTableTag.java:251)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.TableTag.printTable(TableTag.java:613)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:296)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.doEndTag(CursoredTableTag.java:72)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag5(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:420)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag4(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:321)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag1(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:185)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jspService(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:104)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1112)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:686)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:698)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:723)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(BeanUtils.java:265)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.renderer.DefaultCellRenderer.doRender(DefaultCellRenderer.java:39)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.printTableRows(CursoredTableTag.java:235)
    ... 111 more
Caused by:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.printTableRows(CursoredTableTag.java:251)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.TableTag.printTable(TableTag.java:613)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:296)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.doEndTag(CursoredTableTag.java:72)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag5(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:420)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag4(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:321)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jsp__tag1(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:185)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp._diagnostics.__viewdatasourcelogtable._jspService(__viewdatasourcelogtable.java:104)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:526)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.scoping.internal.ScopedRequestDispatcher.include(ScopedRequestDispatcher.java:119)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.JspContent.beginRender(JspContent.java:552)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.beginRender(NetuiContent.java:365)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:485)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._wlsconsole.__nolayout._jspService(__nolayout.java:119)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._wlsconsole.__twocollayout._jspService(__twocollayout.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:211)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:196)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'datasource'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1112)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:686)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:698)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:723)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(BeanUtils.java:265)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.renderer.DefaultCellRenderer.doRender(DefaultCellRenderer.java:39)
    at com.bea.console.taglib.html.CursoredTableTag.printTableRows(CursoredTableTag.java:235)
    ... 111 more
```

Comment: Looks like datasource configuration for database is missing.

Comment: @Sambit The WAR I am deploying doesn't have any database connection

Comment: It is about weblogic datasource configuration. That is why it is throwing. Check more details on datasource configuration for weblogic.

Comment: @Sambit I am new commer for Weblogic, Can you help me understand where should I look in "Weblogic Administration Consol"

Comment: Look into it. https://trinamix.com/configure-data-source-oracle-weblogic-server/

Comment: What is the status of your application after you deployed it ? Acive, Failed, Installed, etc... ? Can you share the weblogic server log snippet showing the issue when you deploy your application ?

Comment: I looked into the URL shared by @Sambit and it started working fine.